# Why I get this message when sending POST request net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, endpoint

When sending my POST requesst I get such the message in browser network and also testing it in postman I receive such the message: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000, but I completely confident that the endpoint are correct because authorization logic completely worked and also database works okay ( that is writen on node.js )
When clicking on submit button to register user and get his/her data to database so that get jwt token I receive such message to console from fetching this endpoint

Fetching data error: AxiosError: Network Error
Register.jsx:18

```
   POST https://localhost:8000/auth/registration net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have tried to change the port but it didn`nt help I also wrote a testing wether the port is open and it showed that it isn`t

server.js:
`

```
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const authRouter = require("./routes/authRouter.js")
const net = require("net")

const PORT = 8000

const app = express()
app.use(express.json({ extended: true}))
app.use("/auth", authRouter)

const DB_URL = `mongodb+srv://yurailchshyn:register@jwttodo.xvuveru.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

app.get("/getter", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: "Hello"})
})

class PortChecker {

    async testPort(port, host) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const socket = new net.Socket()

            socket.on("connect", () => {
                socket.destroy()
                resolve("yes")
            })

            socket.on("timeout", () => {
                socket.destroy()
                resolve("no (timeout)")
            })

            socket.on("error", () => {
                socket.destroy()
                resolve("no (error)")
            })

            socket.connect(port, host)
        })
    }
}

app.get("/something", (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).end("Some hello")
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: "something went wrong"})
    }
})

let pc = new PortChecker

pc.testPort(5000, "127.0.0.1").then((result) => {
    console.log(`Is port open? ${result}`)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Fatal error", error)
    process.exit(1)
})

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(DB_URL)
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is working on PORT: ${PORT}`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Server is not working!!!", error)
    }
}

start()
```

`

Comment: Can you also share the code from your authRouter.js file so that others will be able to assist you better?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.